# Falha ao realizar requisição com Angular.js $http is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou começando a utilizar o angular.js, estou estudando um [Tutorial (Guia Definitivo para Aprender AngularJS em Um Dia)](http://javascriptbrasil.com/2013/10/18/guia-definitivo-para-aprender-angularjs-em-um-dia/), mas de inicio eu já tive problemas com a requisição $http. Estou recebendo a mensagem:  $http is not defined

No Header do index eu inclui:

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.1/angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

Meu HTML:

```
{% verbatim %}
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-controller="sbMenuTopSupport">
        <li ><a href="{{support.action.uri}}">{{support.action.label}}</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>

        </li>
    </ul>
{% endverbatim %}
```

Meu javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sbMenuTop = angular.module('sbMenuTop', []);
    sbMenuTop.controller('sbMenuTopSupport', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.support = {};
            $scope.support.action = {
                "uri": "/SBSystem/web/app_dev.php/support/status.json",
                "label": "Unavailable"
            };
            $scope.support.access = {
                "ipaddress": null,
                "username": null,
                "password": null
            };

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: $scope.support.action.uri
            }).sucess(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.support = data;
                //recuperação de dados bem sucedida
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //alguma erro ocorreu :(
            });
        }]);
</script>
```

Essas são as mensagens de erro que recebo:

```
 ReferenceError: $http is not defined
    at new <anonymous> ((index):128)
    at d (angular-1.0.1.min.js:27)
    at Object.instantiate (angular-1.0.1.min.js:27)
    at $get (angular-1.0.1.min.js:50)
    at angular-1.0.1.min.js:42
    at m (angular-1.0.1.min.js:6)
    at k (angular-1.0.1.min.js:42)
    at e (angular-1.0.1.min.js:38)
    at e (angular-1.0.1.min.js:38)
    at e (angular-1.0.1.min.js:38)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não definiu como dependência do controller o serviço `$http`.

A definição do controller deve ficar assim:

```
sbMenuTop.controller('sbMenuTopSupport', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
```

Comment: O tutorial que eu peguei realmente não está muito legal, além de faltar definir a dependência no construtor o promise está com sintaxe errada: sucess onde deveria ser success.